# Is it possible to have a Glassfish JAAS realm sharing some classes with one installed application?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, neo4j, jaas

In my company, we're developping an application which stores its data in a Neo4j DB using a [semi-custom persistence layer](https://github.com/Riduidel/gaedo). Using that persistence layer, we declared our security layer using classical classes : `User`, `Group`, `Privilege` and so on.

These elements are naturally persisted to our Neo4J DB.

Unfortunatly, we now want to declare our custom JAAS realm, usign that Neo4J DB as back-end. To write that realm in the fastest possible fashion, we decided to use our application code in that realm (by the grace of a maven `<dependency/>`).

Unfortunatly, we have discovered that, when we deploy our JAAS realm, application code fail to load wih various

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: EJB Container initialization error 
Exception while loading the app : EJB Container initialization error
```

Maybe is it linked to the fact that we deploy our JAAS realm in `${domaindir}/lib` ?

Anyway, is there a solution to have one glassfish JAAS realm share some code with one application deployed in domain ?

Comment: Do you have a more comprehensive stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that the JAAS classes are deployed to /domain/lib (which seems correct me). 
I assume that your application classes are deployed as a WAR or EAR.

If your implementation of the JAAS realm depends on classes that are in the WAR/EAR, you get classloading issues because of classloader hierarchy.
The /domain/lib classloader cannot access classes in your WAR/EAR.

You should extract the depending classes to a separate jar and put them in /domain/lib too.

See here for more info about the classloader hierarchy: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beadf.html

Comment: Well, I ended up extracting used classes through an execution of maven-jar-plugin, but answer is conceptually correct. Don't forget, however, to redeploy that model jar when redeploying, as it otherwise leads to incredibly strange exceptions.